# setting the NR to 1 does not work (awk)

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following script in bash.

```sh
awk -F ":" '{if($1 ~ "^fall") 
                      { NR==1
                      {{printf "\t<course id=\"%s\">\n",$1} } } }' file1.txt > container.xml
```

So what I have a small file. If ANY line starts with **fall**, then I want the first field of the VERY first line.

So I did that in the code and set `NR==1`. However, it does not do the job!!!

Comment: You can't set `NR`. If you need something from the first line, save it in a variable.

Comment: You certainly can't set any variable using `==`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F: 'NR==1 {id=$1} $1~/^fall/ {printf "\t<course id=\"%s\">\n",id}' file1.txt > container.xml
```

Notes:

- `NR==1 {id=$1}`

  This saves the course ID from the first line
- `$1~/^fall/ {printf "\t<course id=\"%s\">\n",id}`

  If any line begins with `fall`, then the course ID is printed.
- The above code illustrates that `awk` commands can be preceded by conditions.  Thus, `id=$1` is executed *only if*  we are on the first line: `NR==1`.  If this way, it is often unnecessary to have explicit `if` statements.
- In `awk`, assignment with done with `=` while tests for equality are done with `==`.

If this doesn't do what you want, then please add sample input and corresponding desired output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: 'NR==1{x=$1}/^fail/{printf "\t<course id=\"%s\">\n",x;exit}' file
```

Note:

- if the file has **any** line beginning with `fail`, print the 1st field in very first line in certain format (xml tag).
- no matter how many lines with `fail` as start, it outputs the xml tag **only once**.
- if the file has no line starts with `fail`, it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS = ":"
}
NR==1 {
  foo = $1
}
/^fall/ {
  printf "\t<course id=\"%s\">\n", foo
}
```

Also note

> BUGS
>   The `-F` option is not necessary given the command line variable assignment
>   feature; it remains only for backwards compatibility.

[awk man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)